# Connect to Oracle DB remotely using bash script

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement to connect to Oracle DB from machine A to Machine B(DB).

How to achieve this?

Comment: You say in the title "using bash script" but have tagged Oracle SQL Developer; how do you expect to use a bash script with the SQL Developer IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Weird tagging aside, if you're trying to access / operate on an Oracle DB via a Bash script the two main commands you'll want to look at are:

- sqlplus (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/qstart.htm#i1055567)
- sqlloader (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm)

SQLPlus will allow you to connect and run a prepared SQL script, and SQLLoader will allow you to perform a bulk load into an existing table.